# Do we need a language to think?

Tags: humans, language

I don't know whether this is the right place to ask this question. I have always wondered whether a language is needed to think. When I actively think, I automatically use my mother tongue to do so, and this will probably be the same for most people.

I know that people who cannot hear or speak are able to think, but how exactly?

Do we really need a language to think?

Comment: I'm also not certain if this is the right forum for such a question, but IMHO, we all subvocalize in our native tongue, but I think we think in images and actions.  Consider when you respond to a simulae without a thought; slapping a fast approaching object out of the air or ducking out of the way if it is too big.  There is no sub-vocalization or language, but there is definitely thought.  A choice is made of which action is best and then that action is acted upon... all in less time that it would take to shout "look out".

Comment: If you could edit your question and frame it in a world building context it could be a very good question. E.G: In designing a population for my world, do they need a language to form complex thoughts? What if the population was deaf, or mute?

Comment: No, we don't need language to think. That's not to say that language has no value in the cognitive process, as language allows to pinpoint abstract concepts. Regardless, language before being auditory is symbolic. A language based on signs or pictures could allow abstract thought as much as an auditory one. What happens is that you subvocalize your thoughts, consider that your "mental voice" is an auditory representation of your cognitive process. It acts as an internal feedback loop, easing the creation of memories regarding your thoughts (it makes it easier to remember what you think).

Comment: Have you done any research on the topic?  Putting your title, "Do we need a language to think?" into Google gives quite a lot of content on the question.  Most agree that the question is heavily under specified if asked the way to asked it.

Comment: As is, this feels more like a philosophy or cognitive science question, rather than a worldbuilding one.

Comment: Have you ever had a concept you had to struggle to put into words?
I know *I* have. So, no. (it's not terribly world-buildy, as questions go, though I've read multiple stories that play with the concept)

Comment: Absolutely not! this is similar to can a car drive with a map? The car requires a driver just like thinking is associated with memories and experience since fetus and map helps to negotiate turns etc just like a language helps you to convey message to others. However your level of proficiency or being multilingual depends on the type of car and the condition of the road.

Comment: Whoa! Way to ask one of the most difficult questions of philosophy like it's just a lightweight worldbuilding quiz :)

Comment: @The Nate: I've never been able to explain to anyone how I do complex coding.  As best I can tell from introspection, I don't really use language (even computer languages) for most of the basic ideas that go into a solution.

Comment: @jamesqf Exactly. This notion has so little support and plenty of evidence against. I wonder how it manages to be so very persistent.

Answer (score 10):

This is your friendly neighborhood cognitive science fanatic - this question is poorly-worded, because it is asking about thought in general, when it is fairly obvious to most observers that animals think. What is meant, more likely, is to ask whether *human thought* is possible without language. This is a variation of the Sapir-Whorf  Hypothesis, which posits our language affects how we think about things - e.g., if we have more words for shades of blue, especially ones thay conceptualize them as totally different colors, then we will be more apt to differentiate between shades of blue.

In this sense, it is difficult to deny that human language influences thought. Look up Japanese street lights; color naming differences between Japanese and English have led to a fun postwar phenomenon in that the color of their "Go" light on traffic lights - normally green as an American would think of it - is in fact rather more blue...

But all that aside, if one has no language, can one have concepts equivalent to those of a linguistically-gifted individual? This is a more difficult and freighted question. As others have intimated, Pinker believed an underlying "mentalese" was built in to the human brain, providing a  structure - a computational architecture, if we feel like pleasing the Functionalists - on which other languages were built and to which a mind fell back if no natural language was known. Problematically, we are left to determine what exactly the benefit of layering natural language over mentalese has for us, but perhaps it is an extension of the need to express thought externally which gives rise to the otherwise superfluous languages.

The alternative is to suppose that there is no language or protolanguage at all in the human mind, and that our language is fully a synthetic creation, which would mean thoughts prior to language learning would be by definition without concept - simply the apprehension of raw stimulus by a conscious mind, as perhaps a mouse might. This has its own problems, one of which is it doesn't explain how humans are so universally good at language.

I tend to fall into the prior camp. Part of this has to do with how difficult it ends up being to rigorously define "language" - much as we may conceive of nigh any set as a system, we may conceive of any system which we *derive* information from to be a language. It therefore seems likely that on some level, we are always thinking using some sort of "language."

I will close, however, on a quote from Helen Keller that has always fascinated me. She said of her preliterate life that it was:

"...a conscious time of nothingness. I did not know that I knew aught or that I lived or acted. I had neither will nor intellect. . . I had no power of thought."

Comment: Asking someone who learned language later in life is probably the definitive answer!

Comment: @JDługosz, at first glance, I would agree. However, because language is poorly defined, and because Helen Keller does in a sense contradict herself within that quote alone, I'm not 100% convinced by her claim. Still, a fascinating insight into the quality of preliterate consciousness nonetheless.

Comment: Also, just being able to communicate with other human beings offered many thousands of times more things to think about for Helen Keller. Thoughts go from "I'm hungry, I'm tired", because those are the only thoughts that all people conceive of independently to complicated thoughts about ideas and the outside world.

Comment: Eh, I don't know about that. I'm sure she felt the full range of emotions.

Comment: Testosterone and estrogen both influence thought, yet neither are required for it. (beyond the minima to produce a functioning body, I suppose) The correlation is backwards. We have language centers that, when we think, attempt to translate ideas into language. (What's that model called, oh, cog.sci. wonk?)

Comment: @TheNate, I'm the neighborhood cogsci guy, not the wonk. I have no idea what the name of that model is. Also, you really ought to read my whole response. I don't disagree with you, I think.

Comment: @TheNate from my understanding of Broca's and Wernicke's areas, the brain basically has partitioned comprehension from composition, so I find it difficult to accept the idea that thought has no specialized language-like basis in the human brain. We have really actually evolved to do so, it would seem to me. Then there's the issue of conscious vs. unconscious thougt; for us to be conscious of it, anyway, it seems we must usually access our thoughts through the intermediary of language. I realize now I had made the assumption we are dealing with conscious thought only here.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on whether you're talking about basic cognition or full-on human-level thought. Animals for instance, can think without language, although their thoughts are of course much less complicated than human thought. On the other hand, children who are neglected and never learn to speak are severely mentally handicapped for the rest of their lives, not just in speaking, but in all areas of intelligence. This could indicate that language is important for cognition.

Now, neither of these are really very convincing. But my opinion is that the answer to your question is, no. Anecdotally, athletes don't think to themselves in words when they make split-second decisions on the field. Nor do great musicians or mathematicians.

Again, that's not a fully convincing example, so let me try a philosophical tack. Can language really be the fundamental unit of thought? That is, when a thought first pops into your mind, does it come pre-formed with words assembled into sentences and paragraphs? If this is the case, how would people be able to think of things that they do not have words to express, such as complicated 3-dimensional reasoning, or music? And isn't human language just a fundamentally clumsy way to express thought? How often do we struggle to say what we really mean?

As an analogy, can you imagine building a computer that "thinks" in English, or even a programming language? Sure, a computer can transcribe its thoughts into a high-level language. But the thoughts, when they are first thought, come as a string of 0s and 1s, and are only later turned into something that can be expressed. Noam Chomsky believes that humans do a similar thing, that humans think in a universal "language of thought," which is only later transcribed into spoken languages like English.

Steven Pinker goes in depth into this in *The Stuff of Thought*, and also *The Language Instinct,* of which I highly recommend the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Absolutely not.

**Proof - Answer the following:**

Do babies think?

Answer: Yes.

Do babies know language?

Answer: Nope.

Q.E.D, language is not needed to think.

Comment: So without language one could only think as well as a baby.

Comment: That becomes much, much harder to test, simply because we do not spend time developing ways to learn high-level knowledge without language.  Do you know how to learn math without language?  I don't... is it possible?  I have no idea!

Comment: You're assuming the answer to the question of whether babies think.  Of course this depends on exactly what you mean by 'think' - after all, by some definitions C. elegans thinks - but in human context it would seem that thinking includes forming memories, and I don't think anyone has been shown to have real memories of things that happened to them before the age of two or so, by which time they've acquired the rudiments of language.

Comment: @JDługosz Not at all what i'm saying - Since the question doesn't qualify what "thinking" is, [I'm simply saying that even without language babies can think.](https://www.ted.com/talks/alison_gopnik_what_do_babies_think/transcript?language=en) A genius baby may be able to think at higher levels, who knows?

Comment: @jamesqf see above - the link is a ted-talk link

Comment: I’m pointing out that your QED only shows that babies think *as well as babies* without language and you might actually use this as an argument for the opposite, that cognition is very limited until language is acquired.

Comment: @JDługosz I see what you're pointing out, and my counter argument is that it doesn't matter with regards to the question because all the question asks is "can they think" - at what level they think makes no difference.

Comment: @Aify: But that link still depends on what you're defining as 'thinking'.  By some definitions, anything with a nervous system 'thinks', and you could probably extend that to some plants and electronic devices :-)